# end of quiz results page not displaying properly Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a quiz with 7 questions. Each question has a value in a button that is accumulated until it reaches the results page. At the end, I want it to display an image dependent upon the accumulated values.  It is kind of working but shifting all over the place.  Also the first result is showing up throughout the quiz.

Also, if you have a suggestion on how I can better simplify this code, I would appreciate it.

Also, not sure why Question 2 doesn't show all the buttons properly in this post but it does run properly on my end.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
 function qHome () {
  $("#bkgHome").show();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#goat").hide();
  $("#fish").hide();
  $("#bird").hide();
 }
 $(qHome).on("load", qHome);
 
 
 
 function queHomeClick () {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").show();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#goat").hide();
  $("#fish").hide();
  $("#bird").hide();
 }
 $("#begin").on('click', queHomeClick);
 
  function que1Click () {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").show();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#goat").hide();
  $("#fish").hide();
  $("#bird").hide();
 }
 $("#scary_height").on('click', que1Click);
 $("#small_space").on('click', que1Click);
 $("#scary_fire").on('click', que1Click);
 $("#scary_animals").on('click', que1Click);
 
  function que2Click () {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").show();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#goat").hide();
  $("#fish").hide();
  $("#bird").hide();
 }
 $("#goat").on('click', que2Click);
 $("#fish").on('click', que2Click);
 $("#bird").on('click', que2Click);
 $("#snake").on('click', que2Click);

   function queresults () {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#goat").hide();
  $("#fish").hide();
  $("#bird").hide();
 }

 
 $(".price").hide();
 $("button").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).closest('.box').find('.blue').addClass('samColor');
 });
 $("button").on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).closest('.box').find('.blue').removeClass('samColor');
 });
 $("button").on('click', function() {
  $('.box').removeClass('transBox');
  $(this).closest('.box').addClass('transBox');
 });
 $(".sale").on('click',function() {
  $(".price").fadeIn().show();
 });
 

var accumValue = 0;

$("button").on('click', function() {

    if(!$(this).attr('value')) {
        return;
    }

    accumValue += parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10);
});

$('#finalbutton').on('click', function() {
if (accumValue <=25) {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#goat").show();
  $("#fish").hide();
  $("#bird").hide();

} else if (accumValue > 25 && accumValue <= 70) {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#goat").hide();
  $("#fish").show();
  $("#bird").hide();
} else {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#goat").hide();
  $("#fish").hide();
  $("#bird").show();
}});  

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bkgHome {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}

#bkg1 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg2 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg3 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg4 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg5 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg6 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg7 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg8 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg9 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg10 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#quizHome {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}
#question1 {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}

#question2 {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}
#question3 {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}
#question4 {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}
#question5 {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}
#question6 {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}
#question7 {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}
.results {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
}

h1, h2 {
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
.box {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.7);
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:50px;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:25px;
 line-height:40px;
 padding-bottom:25px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(5,5,5,0.6);
 border-radius: 20px;
 
}
.transBox {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color:rgba(58,57,57,0.8);
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:50px;
 text-align:center;
}

.city {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
.blue {
 background-color: rgba(90,19,17,0.6);
 width:150px;
 height: 40px;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 10px;

}
.samColor {
 background-color:rgba(18,17,23,0.6);;
 width:150px;
 height: 40px;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color:#ffffff;


}

.thumbs {
 border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bkgHome">
<div id="quizHome">
 <ul>
    <li class="box one">
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Are you ready?</span>
       </li>
      </ul>
     <button class="blue" id="begin" value="0">BEGIN</button>
    </li>
</div>
</div>

<div id="bkg1">
<div id="question1">
<h1>Which character are you? Total:</h1>
 <ul>
    <li class="box one">
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being in high places.</span>
        <img src="images/heights.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
     <button class="blue" id="scary_height" value="5">ANSWER  1</button>
    </li>
    <li class ="box two">
            <ul>
       <li class="photos">
       <span class="city">Being in small spaces.</span>
        <img src="images/smallSpace.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
     <button class="blue" id="small_space" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box three">
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">The fear of wild fire.</span>
        <img src="images/fire.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
     <button class="blue" id="scary_fire" value="15">ANSWER  3</button>
    </li>
    <li class = "box four">
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being around scary animals.</span>
        <img src="images/scaryAnimals.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
     <button class="blue" id="scary_animals"value="20">ANSWER  4</button>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="bkg2">
<div id="question2">
<h1>Which character are you?</h1>
 <ul>
    <li class="box one">
     <h2>QUESTION 2 </h2>
     <button class="blue" id="goat" value="5">ANSWER  1</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being in high places.</span>
        <img src="images/heights.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class ="box two">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" id="bird" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
            <ul>
       <li class="photos">
       <span class="city">Being in small spaces.</span>
        <img src="images/smallSpace.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box three">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" id="fish" value="15">ANSWER  3</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">The fear of wild fire.</span>
        <img src="images/fire.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box four">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" id="snake" value="20">ANSWER  4</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being around scary animals.</span>
        <img src="images/scaryAnimals.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>


<div id="bkg3">
<div id="question3">
<h1>Which character are you?</h1>
 <ul>
    <li class="box one">
     <h2>QUESTION 3 <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" value="5">ANSWER  1</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being in high places.</span>
        <img src="images/heights.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class ="box two">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
            <ul>
       <li class="photos">
       <span class="city">Being in small spaces.</span>
        <img src="images/smallSpace.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box three">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" value="15">ANSWER  3</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">The fear of wild fire.</span>
        <img src="images/fire.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box four">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" value="20">ANSWER  4</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being around scary animals.</span>
        <img src="images/scaryAnimals.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
 <button id="finalbutton">Get Results</button>

</div>
</div>
  
    <div id="bkg8">
<div class="results">
<div id="goat">
<h1>Congratulations!  You are a goat!</h1>
<p><img src="images/hammer.png" /></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="bkg9">
<div class="results">
<div id="fish">
<h1>Congratulations!  You a fish!</h1>
<p><img src="images/pliers.png" /></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="bkg10">
<div class="results">
<div id="bird">
<h1>Congratulations!  You are a bird!</h1>
<p><img src="images/hammer.png" /></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you would like someone to debug the whole app for you! RIGHT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to simplify it would be to give each question a class of `question` and then target that when hiding. Hide everything first, *then* show the question you want. For example

```
function queHomeClick () {
    $("#bkgHome").hide();
    $("#question1").show();
    $("#question2").hide();
    $("#question3").hide();
    $("#question4").hide();
    $("#question5").hide();
    $("#question6").hide();
    $("#question7").hide();
    $("#results").hide();
    $("#goat").hide();
    $("#fish").hide();
    $("#bird").hide();
}
$("#begin").on('click', queHomeClick);
```

would become

```
function queHomeClick () {
    $(".question").hide();
    $("#question1").show();
}
$("#begin").on('click', queHomeClick);
```

In fact you can simplify it more by putting this code directly in the on method without a separate function

```
$("#begin").on('click', function () {
    $(".question").hide();
    $("#question1").show();
});
```

It seems like your startup code has a behaviour attached to `qHome`, although `qHome` is a function. If you just want this to run onload you can just put it in the document ready function

Comment: I updated the HTML to include a "question" class and CSS .question class is display:none;  Then for the first section I put inline CSS for .question class as display:block.  For the JS, I removed all the top section and included the function you recommended but I can't get the 2nd question to show up.   I've posted it here on Code Pen http://codepen.io/smeeker/pen/dPWwvZ

Comment: I think the problem is you are hiding the question classes, but the questions themselves are inside these classes. So you show question1 but it's still inside a hidden div

Comment: Ah!  That was it.  Thank you so much for that direction. :)

Comment: I resolved the issue but wanted to break it down further to simply the code even more.  I made a single 'question' class for each of the questions and there is a beginning page and an end result page.  I'm not sure if its an issue with the code aligning to the CSS: $("#begin").on('click', function () {
    $("#quizHome").hide();
    $(this).closest(".question").show();
});
Here is a link to all the code: http://codepen.io/smeeker/pen/dPWwvZ